# If all minors are $0$, then rank is at most $n-2$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, determinant, matrix-rank

Can anyone prove/disprove the following statement?

Given a square matrix of size $n\ge2$, if all of its $(n-1)$-rowed minors are zero, then $\operatorname{rank}(A)\leq n-2$.

I'm having trouble connecting the information on the minors to what I have to prove.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @AnginaSeng It might be the same question, but there is no decent answer there to help the situation. That being said, it's posted 12 hours ago by the same OP, so I'll agree this time.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not help but thank you.

Comment: The following are equal , for any matrix A,(i) dimension of row-space(ii) dimension of column space (iii) number of leading 1's in the unique row-reduced echelon matrix that is row-equivalent to A (iv) largest number r such that A has an rxr submatrix whose determinant is non-zero. A search of the literature will show that, for any of those 4 conditions, there is at least one author who takes that condition as her/his definition of rank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

If all $n-1$-sized minors are $0$, so are the $n$-sized one  (think row expansion of determinant), so all minors of size $\ge n-1$.

Now, let $r$ the largest possible size of a non-zero minor. It is $\le n-2$. (Note, that if all elements of the matrix are $0$, we take $r=0$. Otherwise, $r\ge 1$). Now, you have to show that the columns which contain this minor are a basis for the space of columns. It is a bit involved, but the linear dependence is explicit, using the row expansion of minors of size $r+1$ containing this given minor.